# how does chef controll the building sequence when nodes have dependence

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Assume I need to do such configuration using chef which have two nodes A and B, A has 2 steps and B has 3 steps. The manual sequence is that:

1. Both A and B do step 1
2. A do step 2 (depends on step 1 in B is completed)
3. B do step 2 (depends on step 2 in A is completed)
4. B do step 3

Seems search() in chef can not get the attribute when configure node in parallel.

My question is if there is a way that I can expose some attributes when B has done step 1, then the node A could get the exposed attributes to continue its configuration.(A will keep waiting for the exposed attributes from B)

Answer (score 0):

Chef does not handle this. The best Chef-y approach is generally to make each node convergent (i.e. eventually consistent) and to keep trying to become operational in a loop (usually via chef-client's daemon mode). Remember that Chef is built around a convergent Promise model, which doesn't have "steps", only desired state and current state. That said, the real world is, in fact, procedural and so sometimes it is easier to just go that route. RunDeck and Fabric are my personal recommendations for handling this inter-node orchestration (you would end up with a bunch of RD or Fab tasks that are just `sudo chef-client`), but MCollective and SaltStack are popular too. Chef does have a very basic tool called Chef Push Jobs (or even `knife ssh` if you want to consider that the most basic possible orchestration layer), but I wouldn't recommend using it.